# Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource sharedassets0.resource when splitting application binary in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

I'm trying to publish an Unity app to the PlayStore. Since the size of the app is over the limit of 100MB, I need to split the binary. So I selected the option **Split Application Binary** in Unity.

However, when I try to launch this application (either by downloading it on the Playstore or putting the .apk and the .obb directly on my device from my computer), I get the following errors on Android SDK monitor:

```
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): Error: Cannot create FMOD::Sound instance for resource 
sharedassets0.resource, (File not found. )
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004):  
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): (Filename:  Line: 882)
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): Function SoundHandle::Instance::~Instance() may only be 
called from main thread!
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004):  
01-24 11:38:52.442: E/Unity(25004): (Filename:  Line: 25)
```

The application freezes at the "*Made with Unity*" splash screen.

This is not happening when I don't use the **Split Application Binary** option and put the .apk directly on my device from my computer.

I'm using Unity 5.4.0.

Comment: Did you read this manual https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-OBBsupport.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I wasn't aware I need to manually include code to download the .obb. I'll look at it.

Comment: did u find something?

Comment: I updated to Unity 5.5.1 from 5.4.0. It seems to have fixed the issue. I'll get back to this question when I'll be sure it wasn't something else that was causing it.